# What is solution of this inequation

Tags: inequality, logarithms

I am new to logarithmic inequalities, I want to solve  this

$$ \log_{1.5}\frac{2x-8}{x-2} < 0 $$

I tried:

Converting this into exponential form:

But I don't know whether to take,

$$ (1.5)^0 < \frac{2x-8}{x-2} $$

OR

$$ (1.5)^0 > \frac{2x-8}{x-2} $$

And what to do further.

(I definitely know wavy-curve method for solving inequalities)

Comment: If $a < b$, then $x^a < x^b$ (at least, when $x>0$), so you should go with the latter. Note too that $(1.5)^0 = 1$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When the base of the logarithm is larger than $1$ they are increasing and they are negative when their argument is between $0$ and $1$

so you must solve $\dfrac{2x-8}{x-2} >0 $ *AND* $\dfrac{2x-8}{x-2} <1$

the first is verified for $x<2;\;x>4\quad(*)$

to solve the second remember to move RHS in the LHS and add them together

$\dfrac{2x-8}{x-2} -1<0\to \dfrac{2x-8-x+2}{x-2}<0\to \dfrac{x-6}{x-2}<0$

which is verified for $2<x<6$

we need to find the intersection of the last solution and the solution $\quad(*)$

which is $4<x<6$

Hope this helps

Answer (score 3):

**hint**

$$\log_{1.5}(X)=\frac {\ln (X)}{\ln (1.5)} $$

$$\log_{1.5}(X)<0\iff \ln (X)< 0$$
$$\iff 0 <X <e^0=1$$

so, you solve

$$0 <\frac {2x-8}{x-2}<1$$
or
$$2\frac {x-4}{x-2}>0 \;\; \land \;\; \frac{x-6}{x-2}<0$$

$$\iff (x <2 \lor x>4) \;\land ( 2 <x <6)$$
$$\iff 4 <x <6$$

Answer (score 2):

The function $x\mapsto 1.5^x$ is strictly monotone increasing, so you have
$$\frac{2x-8}{x-2} < 1.$$
Also, you must ensure that the argument of the log function is positive so you actually have 
$$0< \frac{2x-8}{x-2} < 1.$$

Comment: What is meant by monotone increasing

Comment: $f$ is strictly monotone increasing if $x < y\implies f(x) < f(y).$

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively:
$$\log_{1.5}\frac{2x-8}{x-2}<0 \Rightarrow \log_{1.5}(2x-8)-\log_{1.5}(x-2)<0 \Rightarrow \log_{1.5}(2x-8)<\log_{1.5}(x-2) \Rightarrow$$
$$0<2x-8<x-2 \Rightarrow 4<x<6.$$